# Is it possible to join batch data with streaming data in Apache beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wonder whether it is possible to join batch data with streaming data in apache-beam, something like below:

```
import apache_beam as beam

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.external.kafka import ReadFromKafka


def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(["--runner=DirectRunner"])) as p:
        batch_data = (
            p
            | 'ReadMyFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText("s3://my_batch_data.txt")
            | beam.Map(batch_processing_func)
        )
        streaming_data = (
            p
            | 'Read data' >> ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config={"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"},
                topics=["my-first-topic2"],
            )
            | beam.Map(streaming_processing_func)
        )
        joined_data = ({'batch_data': batch_data, 'streaming_data': streaming_data} | beam.CoGroupByKey())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

The reason that I'm curious about it is that it looks like Google Dataflow supports only either of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. The answer is: **yes**, you can join batch data with streaming.

For your particular pipeline, the likely easiest way is to define a side input for your batch data, and use that to *enrich* your stream:

```
def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(["--runner=DirectRunner"])) as p:
        batch_data_si = beam.pvalue.AsList(
            p
            | 'ReadMyFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText("s3://my_batch_data.txt")
            | beam.Map(batch_processing_func)
        )
        streaming_data = (
            p
            | 'Read data' >> ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config={"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"},
                topics=["my-first-topic2"],
            )
            | beam.Map(streaming_processing_func)
        )
        joined_data = (streaming_data 
                       | beam.Map(enrich_stream, batch_data_si))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Where your `enrich_stream` function looks something like this:

```
def enrich_stream(element, batch_side_input):
  element = dict(element)  # make a copy of the first element
  element['special_element'] = batch_side_input[elm['index']]  # or something like that : )
  return element
```

Comment: Glad to have advice from the SNU alumni! I'll try with your code. BTW `CoGroupByKey` will not work in this case?

Comment: : ) - that's right. CoGBK would not work well in this case - it works best for batch pipelines. Side inputs or stateful dofns work best for streaming joins

Comment: Unfortunately, I was faced with an error: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12586 :( Looks like Kenneth refer you on the comment? lol

Comment: Since DirectRunner didn't work on streaming data, I used Dataflow instead ,and it worked. Btw, is there any way to pass `Dataframe`(generated by `to_dataframe()`) as a side input? The reason is that I have to join data by the `value` but if I pass the batch data as a List, it will take O(n) for each streaming.. So I will try to utilize the pandas operation.